# splice returned object has properties undefined. why?

Tags: javascript

Let's consider a definition as

```
    function Stone()  {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 400;

    };
```

I instantiate an object

```
var st = new Stone;

var ll = [st];

var remov = ll.splice(0, 1);

alert(remov.x);
```

here remov removes the object from the list but all the properties are set to undefined. The alert will alert "undefined". Why is this the case?

Comment: Your alert should be `alert(remov[0].x)`

Comment: [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): "_Return value: **An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned**. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned._"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to access the current item. `Splice` can return you an **array of many items**, and if it has one item, it still returns to you an array with one item. So you need to get that item and that access it's properties. For more about `splice` you can see in the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

You can log your `remov` and see what it contains.

```js
function Stone()  {
   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 400;
};


var st = new Stone;

var ll = [st];

var remov = ll.splice(0, 1);
console.log(remov);
alert(remov[0].x);
```